# How do I get a linux kernel patch set from the mailing list?

Tags: linux-kernel, git, patch

I don't subscribe to the linux-kernel mailing list, but I want to get a set of patches that were posted a few weeks ago and apply them to my kernel for testing.  I'm very familiar with patching, building, etc.  My question is, what's the best way to get a copy of this patch set?  It's not applied to any Git repo that I'm aware of, it's just been posted to the mailing list for discussion.

I find a number of sites that archive the linux-kernel mailing list and I can see the set of patches there, but none of these sites have any method (that I can find) of downloading the raw email so I can use "git apply" or "patch" or whatever.  Just copy/pasting the content from my web browser seems like it will not be very successful due to whitespace differences etc.

How do people manage this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062389/how-to-use-git-am-to-apply-patches-from-email-messages

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://marc.info/ has a link for each message to get the raw body, and https://lkml.org/ has (in the sidebar) links to download any contained diffs.

There are also archives with NNTP access that may provide raw messages, though I haven't tried this.

Comment: I didn't see the link from LKML since I was looking at the header email from the patch set with no diff.  Thanks.  This is pretty darn unpleasant: I was hoping for something that would let me select a set of messages and save them as a raw mbox, or even let me download a day's worth as a raw mbox (I can edit it locally).  For any patch set of significant size this will be very painful.  But, it will work!  Thanks.

Comment: I also found this: https://patchwork.kernel.org/ which is a LITTLE simpler to download, but still a lot of clicking etc.  Plus there's no good search I can find, and if you jump into a patch set in the middle after a google search it doesn't seem like there're any "next / previous" links

Comment: For some reason https://patchwork.kernel.org/ seems not to have the `devicetree` mailing list that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 8):

I found part of the answer. It looks like `git` can take the following switch to apply a set of patches you have in an email to a code base you've previously checked out:

```
$ git applymbox /tmp/mbox
```

This article titled: [Git for the newbie](https://home.regit.org/technical-articles/git-for-the-newbie/), had several other examples for dealing with the Linux Kernel using git & patching.

#### ketchup

I think the tool you're looking for is called `ketchup`. Main site appears to be [here](https://github.com/psomas/ketchup). There's a blog post about it here, titled: [ketchup, or how to manage your kernel sources more efficiently](http://psomas.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/ketchup-or-how-to-manage-your-kernel-sources-more-efficiently/). There's also an example of it's usage in the OReilly book titled: [Helpful Utilities: Appendix A - Linux Kernel in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/linux/excerpts/9780596100797/helpful-utilities.html).

#### References

- [Releasing to Linux kernel using patches and emails](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Releasing_to_Linux_kernel_using_patches_and_emails)
- [Git - ti.com tutorial for dealing with processor development](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php?title=Git)

Comment: Yes, of course.  As I mentioned in my question, I'm very familiar with patching and building the kernel.  But my question is, where do I get the file containing the patches (the "/tmp/mbox" file in your example)?  The post says "save the mail", but save it from _where_?  You can't just save it from the web-based mail archives (at least not the ones I've found) because you get a big bunch of HTML-encoded stuff that can't be used for patching.

Comment: @MadScientist - yes I agree that it's sub-optimal. The above saves you a step of saving a file out if you're using something like `mutt`, the mbox files can be setup if you're subscribed to a mailing list where the patches are being emailed to. Still seems like there has to be a better way, I'll keep digging.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm NOT subscribed to the mailing list.

Comment: ketchup cannot extract patch sets from the mailing list as far as I can tell.  It's just able to download patch sets that are already bundled and available as patch files on kernel.org.

Comment: @MadScientist - I believe you're correct. I was thinking you could use it to download patches that have been tagged outside of the emails, using the emails only as a reference to the tags that you're interested in. You should've held off accepting the answer. Seems like there has to be a better method than manually copying them down? Knowing programmer types, they're lazy and would never put up with that workflow for too long 8-).

Comment: If someone comes up with a better answer I'll accept it.

Comment: How to you get the mbox file in the first place usually?

Answer (score 5):

If the mailing list for the project you want to apply patches from uses [public-inbox](https://public-inbox.org/README.html), which is the case for [most Linux subprojects and Git](https://lore.kernel.org/lists.html), you can use the [`b4 am`](https://pypi.org/project/b4/) tool to download the most recent version of a patch series and pipe it to `git am`:

```bsh
b4 am -o- $url | git am
```

where `url` is the URL of any message in the thread.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways I know.

1. patchwork (https://patchwork.kernel.org/)
   pwclient (https://www.varnish-cache.org/patchwork/help/pwclient/) working with patchwork can download patches from emailing list.
2. `git am`
   very simple to use.

   1. save your email sent from git send-email (the extension of Thunderbird is `.eml`).
   2. run `git am xxx.eml`

Comment: pwclient link is now broken - a casual search hasn't found a new source.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.kernel.org/lore.html has archives of many Linux-related lists, including linux-kernel.  The archives are searchable and it's easy to download a raw message or an mbox of an entire thread.