# How download complete patch series from patchwork?

Tags: linux-kernel, git, patch

I want to download the patch series [RFC PATCH 00/26 i.MX5/6 IPUv3 CSI/IC](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.video-input-infrastructure/78686)

In patchwork I can get access to individual patches https://patchwork.linuxtv.org/patch/24331/. But downloading 26 patches and then applying them one by one gets tedious. Is there a way to download the complete patch series with patchwork or by other means?

The question [How do I get a linux kernel patch set from the mailing list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80519/how-do-i-get-a-linux-kernel-patch-set-from-the-mailing-list) suggests marc.info and lkml.org for downloading individual patches but I want the whole series at once. How do I do that?

Comment: `git pw` does a job quite nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The patchwork project information page at https://patchwork.linuxtv.org/project/linux-media/ has a couple of links at the bottom to pwclient and a sample .pwclientrc

Once you set these up, you can use `pwclient list` to search for patches and `pwclient git-am` to apply them. The awkward part is that there's apparently no single command to search and apply in one go. I used a combination of the two to get (for example) Philipp Zabel's recent IPU CSI patch series like this...

```
pwclient list -w "Philipp Zabel" -s New v2 -f %{id} | egrep '^[0-9]' | xargs pwclient git-am
```

Comment: Not all patchworks provides a "front page" to it. OTOH the address [should be constant](http://patchwork.readthedocs.io/projects/pwclient/en/latest/pwclientrc/) for every patchwork. And you could append `curl 'https://patchwork.linuxtv.org/project/linux-media/pwclientrc/' | sed '7,8s/^#//g' > ~/.pwclientrc &&` to that to make everything straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ian-Arkver's answer, if your mailing list supports at least patchwork [2.0](https://lists.ozlabs.org/pipermail/patchwork/2017-August/004549.html) you can also use [git-pw](http://patchwork.readthedocs.io/projects/git-pw/en/latest/). Which can handle series directly (for the moment only ozlabs seems to have updated though, so I'll just make an artificial example)

`git-pw --server https://patchwork.ozlabs.org --project linux-imx series apply 34215`

Please take note, you'll also need to provide authentication with either their api token or your account credentials.

Comment: FDO and kernel.org are using 2.0+ versions of patchwork.

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of is to access `gmane.linux.drivers.video-input-infrastructure` mailing list using `Gmane` NNTP interface with a client and download all messages. For example, you can use a command-line client called `slrn`. There are also many `GUI` clients available. Many of them are capable of downloading multiple messages in `mbox` format.

Answer (score 0):

From (at least) `patchwork` 2.2.0 on, there is a button for that on the top right called "series", which will start a download for a `.patch` file that you can apply using

```bash
git am the-file.patch
```

[Example Patch Series](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/buildroot/cover/20240304153253.732708-1-dario.binacchi@amarulasolutions.com/)