# How can I get a set of patch files that can be applied to increase a Linux version?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, git, patch

I need a method to get a set of patches, that when applied in succession, can take Linux 5.x to Linux 5.y.

Here's what I've tried (I would greatly appreciate feedback on **why** this doesn't work):

1. (Clone Linux with git)
2. `git checkout v5.12`
3. `git format-patch v5.11`

The above steps produce about 13,000 patch files. However, when I apply these in succession to Linux 5.11, a number of them fail to apply. Specifically, there are errors about how some of the patch hunks have already been applied.

Additionally, I have seen this question: [How do I get a linux kernel patch set from the mailing list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80519/how-do-i-get-a-linux-kernel-patch-set-from-the-mailing-list) , but wouldn't the patches I'm getting from my current process be the same set of patches that were emailed to the Linux mailing list?

Answer (score 0):

[`git-format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) doesn’t handle merges, so it can’t be used in your scenario (the Linux kernel development process uses merges extensively).

To produce a patch containing the differences between two versions, use `git diff`:

```
git diff v5.11..v5.12
```

The kernel community publish such patches for you, [look for files starting with `patch-`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/). [`patch-5.12.xz`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/patch-5.12.xz) contains the differences between versions 5.11 and 5.12.

If you want to reconstruct a `git` repository by applying the changes between 5.11 and 5.12, use `git pull`.